# How can I stroke svg multiple circles up to 100 percent?

Tags: svg

I followed a simple example on how to build a simple svg chart. I tried to add multiple circles in the same viewBox which will be filled with color between 0 to 100% but I can’t stroke them to 100%.

stroke-dasharray="75,100"
stroke-dasharray="100,100"

Here is the codepen link. Anyone with the any idea or work around

[https://codepen.io/malawi-realestate/pen/MzKpwp][1]

```
<svg class="circular-chart" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path class="circle-bg" d="M18 1
              a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 46.831
              a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 -46.831"></path><path class="circle circle-ok" d="M18 1
              a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 46.831
              a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 -46.831" stroke-dasharray="100, 100"></path><path class="circle-bg" d="M18 4
             a 20.4155 20.4155 0 0 1 0 40.831
             a 20.4155 20.4155 0 0 1 0 -40.831"></path><path class="circle circle-bad" d="M18 4
             a 20.4155 20.4155 0 0 1 0 40.831
             a 20.4155 20.4155 0 0 1 0 -40.831" stroke-dasharray="75, 100"></path><path class="circle-bg" d="M18 7
             a 17.4155 17.4155 0 0 1 0 34.831
             a 17.4155 17.4155 0 0 1 0 -34.831"></path><path class="circle circle-none" d="M18 7
             a 17.4155 17.4155 0 0 1 0 34.831
             a 17.4155 17.4155 0 0 1 0 -34.831" stroke-dasharray="50, 100"></path><path class="circle-bg" d="M18 10
             a 14.4155 14.4155 0 0 1 0 28.831
             a 14.4155 14.4155 0 0 1 0 -28.831"></path><path class="circle circle-empty" d="M18 10
             a 14.4155 14.4155 0 0 1 0 28.831
             a 14.4155 14.4155 0 0 1 0 -28.831" stroke-dasharray="80, 100"></path><text class="percentage" x="18" y="26">5.5</text><text class="chart-text" x="18" y="30">Your score</text></svg>
```

Comment: the codepen url is https://codepen.io/malawi-realestate/pen/MzKpwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure I understand your question. If you need ro run the animation all around the circle you need to calculate the length of the path. In your case the length of the `.circle-ok` path is the perimeter of the circle

```js
 let perimeter_ok  = 2 * Math.PI * 23.4155;//147.124
```

Alternatively you can use the `getTotalLength()` method to calculate the length of the path

```js
let ok = document.querySelector(".circle-ok")
let perimeter_ok  = ok.getTotalLength();
```

You can use the perimeter to set the `stroke-dasharray` value.

```html
<path class="circle circle-ok" d="..." stroke-dasharray="147.124"></path>
```

if you prefer you can use javascript to set the `stroke-dasharray` value:

```js
ok.setAttributeNS(null, "strokeDasharray", perimeter_ok)
```

In order to animate the path you need to animate the [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) from 100% (147.124 in your case) to 0.

```css
@keyframes progress {
 from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 147.124;
  }
  to{
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

You may also like to read this article first: [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around ;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: .61;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
 from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 147.124;
  }
  to{
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.circle-ok {

  stroke: green;
}


.circle-empty {
  stroke: blue;
}

.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.cb-graph-container{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.chart-text {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.15em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<svg class="circular-chart" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 1
                  a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 46.831
                  a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 -46.831"></path>
  <path class="circle circle-ok" d="M18 1
                  a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 46.831
                  a 23.4155 23.4155 0 0 1 0 -46.831" stroke-dasharray="147.124"></path>
  
  <text class="percentage" x="18" y="26">5.5</text><text class="chart-text" x="18" y="30">Your score</text>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: you've saved my day I have fixed the problem with your guidance. thanks a lot, for the article  link too. https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works .. helpful too.